# EF-Core Related data loading works for one child but not the other

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-key-relationship

In my `ASP.NET Core 1.1`, `EF-Core 1.1 app`, I'm displaying data in a `parent view` that has `partial view`. Scenario is similar to the following: one-to-one relationship between `Customers and Orders table` and between `Customers and Address table`. User selects a customer from a dropdown in the Parent View that has a partial view that displays corresponding orders for the selected customer. Following controller correctly sends customer order details to the view . But, if I replace order entity with address entity the model passed to the Partial view is always null.

**Question**: What I may be missing here?

**Note**: By placing breakpoints, I've verified that the controller below is correctly sending the selected customer's record to the Parent View, and I've also checked in Db that that customer has corresponding address records in addresses table. Another observation is that even if I delete the `FK-relationship` between `customer` and `order` and `address` entities via Visual Studio console and then recreate these relationships the issue remains the same - i.e., it works fin for `order` but not for `address` entity. I've also verified in Db that `FK-relationship` gets correctly created for both the tables.

**Parent:**

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId{ get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    public Order order { get; set; }
    public Address address { get; set; }
}
```

**One Child:**

```
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    public int OrderId{ get; set; }
    public float Price { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer customer{ get; set; }
}
```

**Another Child:**

```
public class Adress
{
    [Key]
    public int AdressId{ get; set; }
    public string street { get; set; }
    ....
    ....
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer customer{ get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**:

```
....
....
Customer mycustomer = _context.Customer.Include(c => c.order).Where(c=> c.CustomerId== selectedId).SingleOrDefault();
....
....
return View(mycustomer);
```

**Parent View**:

```
@model MyProj.Models.Customer

....
@Html.Partial("Partial_orders", Model.order)
....
```

**Partial View**:

```
@model MyProj.Models.Order

....
<div>@Model.CustomerId<div>
....
```

Comment: Looking at your `Customer`, `Order`, and `Address` models, I don't think its a one-to-many relationship (between Customer-Order and Customer-Address), but a one-to-one relationship. Otherwise, your `Customer` model should have `public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }` property and `public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }` property.

Comment: @kimbaudi Yes, it's one-to-one (thanks). I'll correct the typo. But the issues remains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was my bad. In case of address, someone had later disabled the FK-relationship and address table was orphaned. Thanks to those who may have tried to help.

Comment: Please accept this answer so people know it's answered. And now you know why you should read & act on [mcve].

Comment: @philipxy I will. `SO` wants me to wait for some more hours before I can do it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that in your controller, you forgot to include Address when getting Customer.

**So change from**

```
Customer mycustomer = _context.Customer
    .Include(c => c.order)
    .Where(c => c.CustomerId == selectedId)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

**to**

```
Customer mycustomer = _context.Customer
    .Include(c => c.order)
    .Include(c => c.address)
    .Where(c => c.CustomerId == selectedId)
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: No, actually, I've made sure the to check if I've indeed changed `.Include(c => c.order)` to `.Include(c => c.address)`. First, I had both together (as you suggested above) and got the error. Then, in an attempt to narrow down the cause of the error, I just changed `order` to `address` inside `.Include`. Still the same issue.

Comment: That was my bad. In case of address, someone had later disabled the FK-relationship and address table was orphaned. Thank you for trying to help.